# Straining to hit high notes while singing; throat getting dry

Tags: voice

It has come to my attention that I've been straining a lot to hit high notes while singing.  It has gotten harder for me to sing high notes without my throat getting dry.  I don't want to force my voice.  Should I take a couple of days off?  I sing 6 days a week for about 45 minutes.

Comment: Is it winter where you are?  Heated indoor air is incredibly dry, so if it's very cold outside your dry throat is almost certainly attributable to that.

Answer (score 2):

I've been singing for the last 20 years or so in blues and pop styles.  There's a lot of info out there on voice and they often contradict each other.  I've finally accepted that I'm a baritone and change the key to suit my voice.  If you change the key to suit your voice, you'll last much longer, not damage it and not fatigue it so easily.  Keep in mind too that many times the studio take is pushed to the extreme for a vocalist and you'll hear them drop the key when playing live.  Why the obsession with singing higher I'll never know.  I think it's a conspiracy by tenors to make themselves better or something.  Lol.

Furthermore, I've found more or less the middle of my range which feels very comfortable for me to sing in.  Then I can dip into the upper part of my range for dramatic effect and power, but I don't hang out in that part of the voice cause that's when I'll get fatigued and go hoarse.  I can also damage it by doing that.  Just because I can hit higher notes doesn't mean I should be trying to show off all the time.

Come to find out, I sound much better in my middle register.  My voice is lower like Dave Gahan from Depeche Mode, Johnny Cash, and Jim Morrison.  And it just feels so much better singing in that area for me.

Not sure if this helps at all - in other words - be yourself! God created you with your voice for a reason.  Peace.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that you need to sing with more support. Maybe you're using your throat when you're not supposed to and that's why you're getting dry and probably fatigued. When you sing with support, you're not experiencing anything in your throat that hurts so you can keep singing high notes longer. That's the correct way to do it.

However, even if you're singing with the correct support and you're just starting, think about it like a person that just started doing some jogging. At first that person would only be able to run 1 mile, but after some training he would be able to run more and more. The same thing happens with voice support.